# CMD: Поиск файлов по имеющемуся в их имени символу

Tags: bat, cmd

Каким образом с помощью командной строки Windows можно найти файлы, в имени которых есть 1 или 2 повторения конкретного символа?
Например, вывести все файлы папки F, содержащие в имени 1 или 2 буквы A.

Comment: @Gambit, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Ищем файлы с одной буквой А

```
dir /B | findstr /R "^.*A.*$" > uniqinput.txt
```

Ищем файлы с несколькими буквами А

```
dir /B | findstr /R "^.*A.*A.*$" >> uniqinput.txt
```

Проверяем количество символов и удаляем повторяющиеся строки

```
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
set "prev="
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('sort uniqinput.txt') do (
  set curr=%%F
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

  FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=A" %%b IN ("%%F") do (
    if "%%d" == "" (
        if !prev! neq !curr! echo !curr! >> find.txt
    )
  )

  endlocal
  set "prev=%%F"
)
```

Если я правильно всё понял

Comment: Не хватает лишь ограничения. В этом варианте найдутся и файлы, у которых в имени 3 и больше повторений искомого символа.

Comment: @Gambit обновит ответ

Answer (score 0):

Я остановился на таком варианте:
`dir F\ /b | findstr ".*A.*" | findstr /v ".*A.*A.*A.*"`